# JQuery .attr problem. $('#id').attr('value'); returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had this working, and somewhere along the lines I messed something up. Since then I've made several changes trying to get the problem fixed, and now I'm just stuck. As of now I have this:

```
            var calBtn = $('#calButton').attr('value');
        function disappearingTable() {
            if (calBtn = 'Turn Calendar Off') 
            {
                $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
                $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar On');
            }
            else if (calBtn = 'Turn Calendar On') 
            {
                $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
                $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar Off');
            }
        }
```

That's in script tags in the header. Then in the body I have this.

```
<form id="calendarForm" action="javascript:void(0);">
                <input type="submit" id="calButton" value="Turn Calendar Off" onclick="disappearingTable()" />
            </form>
```

I can't figure it out for the life of me. Even when I tried regular Javascript, I still get undefined. Anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly as said by no.good.at.coding `=` is assignment operator and is incorrect even if it works. `==` or `===` is used to test equality

Besides this, if I am not missing anything, the value of variable `calBtn` is set only once outside the function. Whenever the function is invoked in order to get a different value of `calBtn` it needs to be changed in the function or taken from the dom element everytime the function is called .

try this..

```
function disappearingTable() {
            var calBtn = $('#calButton').attr('value');
            if (calBtn ==='Turn Calendar Off') 
            {
                $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
                $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar On');
            }
            else if (calBtn === 'Turn Calendar On') 
            {
                $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
                $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar Off');
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should update your answer with the correct equality operators.

Comment: *facepalm* I moved the var inside, and it works now. I don't now how I managed to move it up outside of the function. Once it was there, though, I didn't think it was wrong. I'm still *really* new to Javascript and JQuery.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is the assignment operator, you should be using `===` or `==` for equality:

```
if (calBtn == 'Turn Calendar Off') 
{
    $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
    $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar On');
}
else if (calBtn == 'Turn Calendar On') 
{
    $('.calendarLayer').toggle();
    $('#calButton').attr('value', 'Turn Calendar Off');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still doesn't work. If I switch to ==, nothing happens at all. With =, the toggle works repeatedly, and the text changes to "Turn Calendar On", but never changes after the first click. For fun I added document.write(calBtn); which is how I came to the conclusion that I had attr problem (Undefined).

Comment: You should use `===` until you know 100% what `==` does.

Comment: Will do. I actually went through and changed all of == to ===, and != to !== earlier when running my code through the validator. Which is also when I managed to mess up my function. Then when trying to figure out what happened I changed all that back, and managed to further mess up the equality in the function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the equality checks, which still do need to be changed, I think you have a problem related to implied globals because your calButton variable lives outside of your function.

What if you refactored your code like so:

```
$('#calButton').click(function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var value = element.val();
    var layer = $('.calendarLayer');

    if (value === 'Turn Calendar Off') {
        layer.toggle();
        element.attr('value', 'Turn Calendar On');
    } else if (value === 'Turn Calendar On') {
        layer.toggle();
        element.attr('value', 'Turn Calendar Off');
    }
});

<form id="calendarForm">
    <input type="submit" id="calButton" value="Turn Calendar Off" />
</form>
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I fixed the equality check as well. Thanks